# Join query display only the first item

Tags: laravel

I try to display the results from the query below but i get only one item .

the query is supposed the display me 2 items

Here my database

> table : compet_equipe (compet_id , equipe_id)

```
compet_id : 2 / equipe_id = 4
compet_id : 2 / equipe_id = 1
```

Competitions has many equipe and equipe has many competitions

Someone know where i'm doing wrong ?

here my query in the controller :

```
$domicile = CompetEquipe::join('equipe' , 'equipe_id' , '=' , 'compet_equipe.equipe_id')
    ->join('structures' , 'structure_id' , '=' , 'equipe.structure_id')
    ->join('catg_equipe' , 'catg_equipe_id' , '=' ,  'equipe.catg_equipe_id')
    ->select('lb_equipe' , 'catg_equipe.lb_catg_equipe' , 'structures.nom_structure')
    ->where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])
    ->get()
    ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
        return [$i->id => $i->lb_equipe.' - '.$i->nom_structure.' - '.$i->lb_catg_equipe];
    });
```

UPDATE WHEN I DO :

```
$domicile = CompetEquipe::where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])
        ->get();

#original: array:2 [▼
        "compet_id" => 1
        "equipe_id" => 2
      ]

#original: array:2 [▼
        "compet_id" => 1
        "equipe_id" => 4
      ]
```

It's working but when i join with equipe to get the name of equipe ect.. the query doesn't work

Comment: Add the columns on which you are joining to the select for the joins to correctly work

Comment: What is your result currently with above query ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually i get the item from compet: 2 / equipe_4 but not also compet_id : 2 / equipe_id :1

Comment: maybe i need to pluck equipe_id ?

Comment: You're not joining with the competition table.

Comment: i don't need to join compet table ! i just want to join equipe to get all the equipes from the compet_id

Comment: The problem comes from ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
                return [$i->equipe_id];
            });

Comment: It's display me only one item and not the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just building out the relations and eager loading? My apologies for any incorrect model names, I am not good with the translations.

```
class Competition extends Model {
    public function equipes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipe', 'compet_equipe');
    }
}
```

and then the query is as follows:

```
$competition = Competition::with('equipes')->find($id);
$equipes = $competition->equipes;
```

Comment: i get the result that i want ! but i would like to pluck or map the result ! how could i do that ?

Comment: does `$competition->equipes->pluck('name')->all()` get what you want?

Comment: i found ! with your help ! $find_equipes = $competition->equipes;
        $domicile = $find_equipes->mapWithKeys(function ($i) {
            return [$i->id => $i->lb_equipe.' - '.$i->structure->nom_structure.' - ' .$i->catg_equipe->lb_catg_equipe];
        });

Comment: Glad I could help!